# Preg_match_all only outputting Numbers. I need letters as well

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am modifying a script to output a string from a long page of text and this works like a charm, the only issue is that the second set will only output numbers.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('page.htm'); 
preg_match_all('#<a.*?href="(?:http://)www.site.com/profiles/(?P<id>\d+)[^‌​>]+#msi',$file, $matches); 
$f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
print_r($matches['id']);
fwrite($f, print_r($matches['id'], true));
fclose($f); 

echo "<br><br>";

preg_match_all('#<a.*?href="(?:http://)www.site.com/id/(?P<id2>\d+)[^‌​>]+#msi',$file, $matches2); 
$f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
print_r($matches2['id2']);
fwrite($f, print_r($matches2['id2'], true));
fclose($f); 
?>
```

The top one is supposed to do that, but the bottom one needs to allow ALL characters including special ones, is there something missing or something I need to add? Thanks a ton!

Comment: I apologize, I included the wrong php file, I put in an old one I was using. The right one is attached now. If there is a way to make what you wrote work with the new php, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meh, figured it out.

Change

```
'#<a.*?href="(?:http://)www.tf2items.com/id/(?P<id2>\w+)[^‌​>]+#msi'
```

to

```
'#<a.*?href="(?:http://)www.tf2items.com/id/(?P<id2>\d+)[^‌​>]+#msi'
```

Apparently \w is letters only (wtf) and \d is everything

Comment: is there something else I should be using?

Comment: Well if it works for you? Just be sure you fully test the result (both for expected positives and negatives).